# How do I bind ctrl-alt-up/down to work like VS2019 in VSCode?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

One of the things I find really annoying about VSCode is that the simple operation of adding another cursor directly above or below the current one (box edit) is bound to a mouse operation! I mean, who takes their hands of the keyboard and uses a mouse to do text editing?

Anyway, I've looked and can't find simple instructions how to bind the shortcut keys crl+alt+up and ctrl+alt+down to work as it does in VS2019, SSMS, etc.. Presumably it's a 2 line edit of a settings file but (a) I don't know which file and (b) |I don't know what function to call.

I assume many people have done and will immediately respond with "paste `this` *here*".

Thanks

Comment: for me that is the default key binding, I have not modified this.

Comment: <insert expletive/> I've bben struggling with that for months if not years and it turns out i<crtl><alt><up>, <ctrl><alt><down> etc are the defalt hotkeys for the Intel graphics card to flip the screen to various orientations! Since I don't have any need for that I've disabled it.

It still doesn't work quite the same way as VS2019, since it doesn't pad short lines, but it's better than nothing. I'll go and see if someone's written an add-on to make it work correctly!

Comment: As you can use it in VS2019 it means it is no longer cached by the Intel driver, or VS2019 catches it first. I'm using nVidia card. VSC's logic might be: how can you place a cursor where there is no character. If needed I pad all the lines with spaces and remove what I don't want. For me this happens very rarely.